# Open multiple tabs from an array with window.open

Tags: arrays, reactjs, tabs, window.open

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work. And please, guide me or come up with an answer where I'm doing wrong.

I have an array, and it that array I have urls. I want window.open to open all these url's at the same time.

The code:

```
const links = ['mypage.com', 'myOtherPage.com', 'myThirdPage.com'];

const openLinks = () => { links.map(link => window.open(link, "_blank")); }

<MyComponent openLinks={openLinks} />
```

The problem with this, is that it only opens up the first URL in the array, and the others are just ignored. Is there a solution to this? What am I missing/doing wrong?

EDIT: I got an answer from a friend, who said: "It's not possible to open more than one link at the time, this is to prevent the user from getting spammed".

So I guess my request is not possible with this approach. Have anyone done something different?

Thanks

Comment: Can you put you code on codesandbox?

Comment: Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qL19wj5b/

Comment: Not sure if this will work but you can try adding timeout between window.open invokes.

Comment: for me your fiddle is working fine. It's opening two windows. May be timeout can solve your problem